# Display Azure AD B2C Sign In Android Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm testing using Azure AD B2C with Xamarin.Forms, specifically with the sample found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/webservices-azureadb2cauth/

The code seems to working fine. All is working with UWP as expected. Haven't tested IOS yet.

On my Android Emulator, when I click the Login button, the Chrome window opens and I get a blank page.

The Debug window shows the following:

[ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
10-13 21:25:37.024 D/        ( 3450): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xca5fe1c0, tid 3450
10-13 21:25:37.024 E/chromium( 3450): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

I've also seen this:
10-13 20:22:55.071 W/com.dandaappdevelopment.shiplog( 2977): type=1400 audit(0.0:953): avc: denied { link } for comm=54687265616420506F6F6C20576F72 name="PropertyStore.forms.tmp" dev="dm-1" ino=123775 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c88,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c88,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0

I have tried the steps shown here with two different versions of Chrome:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/Android-Emulator-with-MSAL

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Westley

Comment: try setting the `WithUseEmbeddedWebView` method and set it to true and see if that helps you. PS: it needs to be called on your Login methods `AuthenticationResult` object

Comment: Hi FreakyAli,

I tried the change and now I get a Non-HTTPS URL cannot be used error.

Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @Westley is App.UIParent not null on this [line](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WebServices/AzureADB2CAuth/ADB2CAuthorization/LoginPage.xaml.cs#L46) when you run android? Are you running the latest version of MSAL.NET in your sample? I'll see if I can get the sample you linked updated as well.

Comment: @Jenny I took a few days off from working on this and now it is crashing before the app fully loads with some type of invalid token error. Not sure what I changed to cause this error, one of the reasons I took a break.

I'll try it again in a few days and report back.

To the best of my knowledge I do have the latest version of MSAL.Net since I just loaded it to start on this project.

Thanks!

Comment: @Westley hmmm...that's not good. do you have a repro you can send me? jeferrie@microsoft.com

Comment: @Jenny Good news! I think I found the problem. In the AndroidManifest.xml file I didn't have the "://auth" as part of the android:scheme string.

I also updated the Identity.Client package from 4.50 to 4.51 which may or may not have been causing the problem with the app even loading.

My next issue, following the sample is getting returned back to the app to open the LogOut page.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Westley i'm not sure I'm following what the new issue is?

Comment: @Jenny On Android it is opening the web page to do the login, but after entering the username/password and clicking SignIn nothing happens. Following the sample, it is supposed to open the Logout page in the app.

It is doing this using UWP but not on Android. Haven't tested IOS yet.

Comment: @Jenny Further testing. I compiled the example code from the first link above and I'm getting the same problem. Clicking Sign In does not bring up the LogoutPage on Android (works for UWP). The only changes I made were to update nuget packages MS.Identity.Client to 4.5.1 & MS.NetCore.UWP to 6.2.9, use my own values in the Constants.cs file, and set my minimum Android level to 19 since it was complaining about being set to level 14.

Comment: @Westley do you have a repro you can share? you can send me a link or email if you want.

Comment: @Jenny The good news is that I finally realized I had a typo in my AndroidManifest.xml file. The bad news is I'm crashing with a Java RunTimeException - Didn't find class "com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"

Sending you an email with the source code.

Comment: @Westley I just emailed you back...you need to remove the `com.` in in the manifest...so have this: ` <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"` instead. I tried it out w/the repro you sent and works fine.