# Problem displaying MSAL login page in Android Emulator using Xamarin.Forms for Android

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to build and run the Android MSAL example provided by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) in VS2019. It builds and starts successfully, but after clicking on the sign in button it opens the browser and navigates the the login page but fails to display it correctly. The VS debug output displays:

```
W/UserDetailsClient.Droid(12360): type=1400 audit(0.0:224): avc: denied { link } for comm=54687265616420506F6F6C20576F72 name="PropertyStore.forms.tmp" dev="dm-1" ino=124432 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I've seen a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369534/display-azure-ad-b2c-sign-in-android-emulator). Updating all the packages to the latest version hasn't resolved the issue.

I've also followed the steps [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/Android-Emulator-with-MSAL) to ensure that Chrome is setup for the Android Emulator.

The android manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <application>
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msala7d8cef0-4145-49b2-a91d-95c54051fa3f" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you follow the steps on the [sample documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/1-Basic#android-specific-considerations) carefully? Also, the sample has been updated recently. I would recommend trying the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that the UWP example works just fine. I have tried with the updated version and that gets as far as prompting me for my credentials. After this it displays a confirmation screen - "Are you trying to sign in to active-directory-Xamarin-native-v2?", but when I confirm it redirects to a black screen with the title ADB2CAuthorization. Unfortunately nothing further happens, from the UWP example I can see it's supposed to display some basic user details.

Comment: Wait there is something fishy there. You shouldnt be seen any "B2C" title since this is not a B2C sample. I know that MSAL samples usually have the same package name, so I think you might be facing an app name conflict in your emulator. Uninstall the 'UserDetailsClient" app that you have installed and try running the app again.

Comment: I've removed all my apps from the android emulator. After re-running it gets as far as the "Are you..." prompt. Clicking on Cancel or Continue it reloads the same brower tab with the same "Are you ..." prompt. The OnActivityResult method isn't hit unless I close the browser tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help @TiagoBrenck, I got there in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. Not being able to progress to the login screen was resolved by using the latest version of the sample.

As for confirming the sign-in and continuing back to the app, the optional step 3b in the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/1-Basic#optional-step-3b-configure-the-android-project-with-your-return-uri) is required for the android demo to work. Without the correct client ID, control is not passed back to the app. After updating the sample file MsalActivity.cs in the UserDetailsClient.Droid project with the included ClientID from App.cs in the UserDetailsClient project it worked.

I initially read this step as optional, and only required updating if you registered the sample as a new app as mentioned in the optional [step 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations).

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations) also explains in better detail the options for updating the android manifest or creating the activity in code.

Comment: For me it was the activity/intent-filter in the android manifest with the hash in the path